# loopback-connector-soap not working: SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations

Tags: node.js, soap, loopbackjs, apiconnect

Since my error log is not in English I try to provide the important parts of the error trance which the IBM API Connect Web interface gives after I try to add a new SOAP Datasource and then try to reload the server.

```
[SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode]

/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:246
     throw err;
```

It tells me to do

```
npm install loopback-connector-soap --save
```

but I mean this is StackOverflow of course, it's not working as intended.

---

Full trace:

```
2017-02-26T20:33:58.661Z pid:63405 worker:4 loopback-connector-soap
2017-02-26T20:33:58.661Z pid:63405 worker:4 Führen Sie zur Behebung Folgendes aus:
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     npm install loopback-connector-soap --save
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at DataSource.setup (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:315:28)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at new DataSource (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:121:8)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at Registry.createDataSource (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:355:12)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at dataSourcesFromConfig (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:440:19)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at EventEmitter.app.dataSource (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:235:14)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at /Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:190:9
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at /Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:281:5
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at Array.forEach (native)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at forEachKeyedObject (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:280:20)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at setupDataSources (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:180:3)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at execute (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:38:3)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at bootLoopBackApp (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/index.js:154:3)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tim/Development/api/test-api/server/server.js:23:1)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.662Z pid:63405 worker:4     at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.663Z pid:63405 worker:4     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
2017-02-26T20:33:58.663Z pid:63405 worker:4     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

---

I'm really new to this so I don't know where to start searching for errors and before I'm doing something

Comment: Can you please provide your npm version, node version, and loopback-connector-soap version. Do you have code written in ES6? So far it seems that you have ES6 code and unsupporting version of node/npm/module for it

Comment: I generated the code via `apic loopback` and have not written something by myself yet.
Node Version is v5.0.0, NPM Version is 3.3.6 and loopback-connector-soap Version is ^4.0.0.

Comment: then I guess (i cant see your system, but i am almost sure) node v.5 is the cause -> if it matters to you to use ES6 code freely upgrade to v.6.9, v.5 supports certain ES6 features only in strict mode, and even do not support some of them at all.

Comment: Thanks that resolved my issue!

Comment: Glad to help! ::)

Comment: @nevotheless can you please post your solution as an answer. It may help other users find a solution if they run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above, this issue was solved by updating the user's Node version. The issue was seen in Node version 5.0.0, but was not present in the updated version 6.9.